# Python Enchant language descriptions

Tags: python, pyenchant

I'm working with the pyenchant module. I couldn't find in their documentaion and anywhere else, the descriptions for the languages listed in enchant.list_languages(). This function returns a list of tags, I need the human friendly descripction of each language.

```
import enchant
enchant.list_languages()
['af', 'am', 'ar', 'bg', 'bn', 'br', 'ca', 'cs', 'cy', 'da', 'de', 'de_AT', 'de_CH', 'de_DE', 'el', 'en', 'en_CA', 'en_GB', 'en_US', 'eo', 'es', 'et', 'eu', 'fa', 'fo', 'fr', 'fr_CH', 'fr_FR', 'ga', 'gl', 'gu', 'he', 'hi', 'hr', 'hsb', 'hu', 'hy', 'id', 'is', 'it', 'kk', 'kn', 'ku', 'lt', 'lv', 'ml', 'mr', 'nb', 'nl', 'nn', 'no', 'nr', 'ns', 'or', 'pa', 'pl', 'pt_BR', 'pt_PT', 'ro', 'ru', 'sk', 'sk_SK', 'sl', 'st', 'sv', 'ta', 'te', 'tl', 'tl_PH', 'tn', 'ts', 'uk', 'uz', 'xh', 'zu']
```

How can I translate all this tags to the human friendly name of these languages ('English', 'Spanish', 'Italian', etc)? Is there a function in pyenchant or another library to accomplish this?

Thanks a lot!!

Comment: [This link](http://www.lingoes.net/en/translator/langcode.htm) seems to give them.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use [pycountry](https://pypi.org/project/pycountry/#description):

To get the language name, you can use:

```
pycountry.languages.get(alpha_2=language)
```

Where `language` is one of the pyenchant languages.

**EDIT**

Here is how you can print the pyenchant language names (and countries):

```py
import pycountry

enchant_codes = [
    "af", "am", "ar", "bg", "bn", "br", "ca", "cs", "cy", "da",
    "de", "de_AT", "de_CH", "de_DE", "el", "en", "en_CA", "en_GB", "en_US", "eo",
    "es", "et", "eu", "fa", "fo", "fr", "fr_CH", "fr_FR", "ga", "gl", "gu",
    "he", "hi", "hr", "hsb", "hu", "hy", "id", "is", "it", "kk",
    "kn", "ku", "lt", "lv", "ml", "mr", "nb", "nl", "nn", "no", "nr",
    "ns", "or", "pa", "pl", "pt_BR", "pt_PT", "ro", "ru", "sk", "sk_SK", "sl",
    "st", "sv", "ta", "te", "tl", "tl_PH", "tn", "ts", "uk", "uz", "xh", "zu",
]

for code in enchant_codes:
    lang_code, _, country_code = code.partition("_")
    if len(lang_code) == 2:
        language = pycountry.languages.get(alpha_2=lang_code)
    elif len(lang_code) == 3:
        language = pycountry.languages.get(alpha_3=lang_code)
    else:
        language = None
    language_name = language.name if language else "(unknown language)"
    country = pycountry.countries.get(alpha_2=country_code) if country_code else None
    country_name = country.name if country else ""
    print(code, "=>", language_name, "/", country_name)
```

Comment: OP wants the name of the language, not the country

Comment: @DeepSpace `pycountry` also gives languages `pycountry.languages.get(alpha_2='an').name`.

Comment: @Arty Ok, but the answer should address that

Comment: Perfect!! Thanks a lot!!